# Spring security roles vs Permissions

Tags: spring, spring-security

Im trying to make a simple web application just to practice an learn more about Spring security.

But I have problems understanding the concepts of roles and permissions.
So far I have created an ADMIN_ROLE and USER_ROLE and applied it to an ADMIN-USER and applied to USER_ROLE to GENERAL-USER. This is working fine without problems.

But now I would like to create a profile page that is accessible to only the owner of that user.

I would appreciate it if you have any resources for me to read of simple explanations of how these concepts work or how you would design this yourself..

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some use, it is [Unixlike file system permissions](http://www.abcseo.com/tech/java/unix-filesystems-permissions-with-spring-security) implemented in Spring

In brief a permission is something you can do on an object - delete, update, read, create and the role is who is doing it: administrator, user, editor etc.

Comment: the external link is broken.